# Remove spaces in dictionary object

Tags: python

Seriously, this seems so easy but none of the methods I found have worked so far.

I have a dict object like this:

```
dict = {'                      key1                    ': ["                value1              ", "                value1_1              "], '                      key2                    ': '                value2             ', '                      key3                    ': ['                value3              ', '                value3_1              '], '                      key4                    ': '                value4              ', '                      key5                    ': ['                value5              ', '                value5_1              ', '                value5_2              ']}
```

but I need it to be like this:

```
{'key1': ["value1", "value1_1"], 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': ['value3', 'value3_1'], 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': ['value5', 'value5_1', 'value5_2']
```

Because some values are lists, I have tried a for loop like this (excuse funny syntax, I just need to make it work for now and will improve syntax later):

```
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if type(v) is list:
            k.replace(' ','')
            k.replace(" ","")
            for i in v:
                i.replace(' ','')
                i.replace(" ","")
        else:
            k.replace(' ','')
            k.replace(" ","")
            i.replace(' ','')
            i.replace(" ","")
```

That didn't work. Then I tried:

```
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if type(v) is list:
            k = k.strip()
            for i in v:
                i = i.strip()
        else:
            k = k.strip()
            v = v.strip()
```

That also did nothing. Help!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate through `dict`'s values to see if they're lists or strings - then use `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` on each string or list value - *and* each key.  Those functions remove left/right whitespace in strings - `strip()` can also be used, it combines rstrip/lstrip.  I would just create a new dictionary to hold these in.

```
dict = {'                      key1                    ': ["                value1              ", "                value1_1              "], '                      key2                    ': '                value2             ', '                      key3                    ': ['                value3              ', '                value3_1              '], '                      key4                    ': '                value4              ', '                      key5                    ': ['                value5              ', '                value5_1              ', '                value5_2              ']}

new_dict = {}

for i in dict.keys():
    if type(dict[i]) is list:
        new_dict[i.rstrip().lstrip()] = [j.rstrip().lstrip() for j in dict[i]]
    else:
        new_dict[i.rstrip().lstrip()] = dict[i].rstrip().lstrip()

print(new_dict)
# {'key1': ['value1', 'value1_1'], 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': ['value3', 'value3_1'], 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': ['value5', 'value5_1', 'value5_2']}
```

Comment: Why not use `.strip()` instead of `.rstrip().lstrip()`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this with a single line of code using *dict comprhension*, *list comprehension* and `strip()`:

```
{k.strip():[s.strip() for s in v] if type(v) is list else v.strip() for k, v in d.items()}
```

return:

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value1_1'],
 'key2': 'value2',
 'key3': ['value3', 'value3_1'],
 'key4': 'value4',
 'key5': ['value5', 'value5_1', 'value5_2']}
```

This is definitely the most pythonic way :-)

Comment: I always love list comprehension. But I already accepted the other answer. Thank you for this way, though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dictionary comprehension:

```
{key.strip():[x.strip() for x in value] if type(value) == list else value.strip() for key, value in dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.strip` does exactly what you want. I'd suggest making a simple method to remove the leading/trailing spaces and just use a very simple dict comprehension (**P.S**: don't use builtins as variable names! I replaced `dict` with `data` below for reference):

```
data = {'                      key1                    ': ["                value1              ", "                value1_1              "], '                      key2                    ': '                value2             ', '                      key3                    ': ['                value3              ', '                value3_1              '], '                      key4                    ': '                value4              ', '                      key5                    ': ['                value5              ', '                value5_1              ', '                value5_2              ']}

def ostrip(o):
    try: return o.strip()
    except: return list(map(str.strip, o))


print({ostrip(k): ostrip(v) for k, v in data.items()})
```

Above `ostrip` just trys to strip it as if it's a string, otherwise assumes it's a list of strings by mapping the method to the list. You could use an `else` statement to catch edge cases although that's up to you.

This results in a dict as follows:

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value1_1'], 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': ['value3', 'value3_1'], 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': ['value5', 'value5_1', 'value5_2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deceptively simple and replaces all whitespace, but:

```
import json
foo = json.loads(json.dumps(foo).replace(' ', ''))
```

It converts the object to text, so whitespace can be removed simultaneously instead of looping through

Comment: This a cool trick, word of warning if there are any spaces in the keys or values that should be preserved this will not preserve those spaces.

Comment: In the example, this shouldn't make a difference, and if it is then (as I think they have done) they can be replaced with underscores

Comment: It works for my dummy example but for my actual test case, I have values such as 'bank account' which is turned into 'bankaccount' so this trick can't be generalized. It's cool, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is close to being correct but since you called the k, v variables from within the loop you must update the dictionary.

```
dict_spaceless = dict()
for k, v in dict.items():
  if type(v) is list:
      k = k.strip()
      v_spaceless = list()
      for i in v:
          i = i.strip()
          v_spaceless.append(i)
  else:
      k = k.strip()
      v_spaceless = v.strip()
  dict_spaceless[k]= v_spaceless
dict=dict_spaceless
```

Also, a good advice is to not call a variable by their initialization method. That is, having a dictionary called 'dict' is very confusing when quickly reading the code since to initialize an empty dictionary in python we call the function dict()